# Not able to scrape Forbes with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table from this website "https://www.forbes.com/fintech/2019/#ef5484d2b4c6"

When i tried to find the main table, it returned the following without the table

> Blockquote ""
> [error message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kygwN.png)

```
url = 'https://www.forbes.com/fintech/2019/#ef5484d2b4c6'
source = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
div1 = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'main-content'})
div1
```

quote:""

Here's the data i am looking for:

[high level section of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iAyP.png)

[Data i would like to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8gJM.png)

Comment: it's good practice to accept a solution if it fits your need, or at least let people know that you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use Selenium to let the page render first, then you could grab that html source and parse with beautifulsoup. Or, you can access that data through their api json response.

the link you'are trying to get is is not in that json response though, but it appears to follow the same format/structure:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/fintech/2019/position/true.json?limit=2000'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for each in data['organizationList']['organizationsLists']:
    orgName = each['organizationName']
    link = 'https://www.forbes.com/companies/%s/?list=fintech' %each['uri']

    print ('%-20s %s' %(orgName, link ))
```

**Output:**

```
Acorns               https://www.forbes.com/companies/acorns/?list=fintech
Addepar              https://www.forbes.com/companies/addepar/?list=fintech
Affirm               https://www.forbes.com/companies/affirm/?list=fintech
Axoni                https://www.forbes.com/companies/axoni/?list=fintech
Ayasdi               https://www.forbes.com/companies/ayasdi/?list=fintech
Behavox              https://www.forbes.com/companies/behavox/?list=fintech
Betterment           https://www.forbes.com/companies/betterment/?list=fintech
Bitfury              https://www.forbes.com/companies/bitfury/?list=fintech
Blend                https://www.forbes.com/companies/blend/?list=fintech
Bolt                 https://www.forbes.com/companies/bolt/?list=fintech
Brex                 https://www.forbes.com/companies/brex/?list=fintech
Cadre                https://www.forbes.com/companies/cadre/?list=fintech
Carta                https://www.forbes.com/companies/carta/?list=fintech
Chime                https://www.forbes.com/companies/chime/?list=fintech
Circle               https://www.forbes.com/companies/circle/?list=fintech
Coinbase             https://www.forbes.com/companies/coinbase/?list=fintech
Credit Karma         https://www.forbes.com/companies/credit-karma/?list=fintech
Cross River          https://www.forbes.com/companies/cross-river/?list=fintech
Digital Reasoning    https://www.forbes.com/companies/digital-reasoning/?list=fintech
Earnin               https://www.forbes.com/companies/earnin/?list=fintech
Enigma               https://www.forbes.com/companies/enigma/?list=fintech
Even                 https://www.forbes.com/companies/even/?list=fintech
Flywire              https://www.forbes.com/companies/flywire/?list=fintech
Forter               https://www.forbes.com/companies/forter/?list=fintech
Fundrise             https://www.forbes.com/companies/fundrise/?list=fintech
Gemini               https://www.forbes.com/companies/gemini/?list=fintech
Guideline            https://www.forbes.com/companies/guideline/?list=fintech
iCapital Network     https://www.forbes.com/companies/icapital-network/?list=fintech
IEX Group            https://www.forbes.com/companies/iex-group/?list=fintech
Kabbage              https://www.forbes.com/companies/kabbage/?list=fintech
Lemonade             https://www.forbes.com/companies/lemonade/?list=fintech
LendingHome          https://www.forbes.com/companies/lendinghome/?list=fintech
Marqeta              https://www.forbes.com/companies/marqeta/?list=fintech
Nova Credit          https://www.forbes.com/companies/nova-credit/?list=fintech
Opendoor             https://www.forbes.com/companies/opendoor/?list=fintech
Personal Capital     https://www.forbes.com/companies/personal-capital/?list=fintech
Plaid                https://www.forbes.com/companies/plaid/?list=fintech
Poynt                https://www.forbes.com/companies/poynt/?list=fintech
Remitly              https://www.forbes.com/companies/remitly/?list=fintech
Ripple               https://www.forbes.com/companies/ripple/?list=fintech
Robinhood            https://www.forbes.com/companies/robinhood/?list=fintech
Roofstock            https://www.forbes.com/companies/roofstock/?list=fintech
Root Insurance       https://www.forbes.com/companies/root-insurance/?list=fintech
Stash                https://www.forbes.com/companies/stash/?list=fintech
Stripe               https://www.forbes.com/companies/stripe/?list=fintech
Symphony             https://www.forbes.com/companies/symphony/?list=fintech
Tala                 https://www.forbes.com/companies/tala/?list=fintech
Toast                https://www.forbes.com/companies/toast/?list=fintech
Tradeshift           https://www.forbes.com/companies/tradeshift/?list=fintech
TransferWise         https://www.forbes.com/companies/transferwise/?list=fintech
```